# Using useDelimiter in Java

Tags: java, printing, delimiter

I have a file that has hyphens for a date.

For example:

```
Abey    F   5-5-1996    0   0   0   0
John    M   5-5-1997    10  10  10  10
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfna5.png "example"

The problem I am having is trying to print put everything in one line.

I have tired:

`line.useDelimiter("[\t \r]");`

`line.useDelimiter("-"); //to remove the hypens.`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename)); 
while(input.hasNextLine()) { 
        Scanner line = new Scanner(input.nextLine()); 
        line.useDelimiter("[\t \r]"); // Tab (\t) and/or space ( ) and/or carriage return (\r) delimited file
        line.useDelimiter ("-");    
        lineno++;
        System.out.println("--------READING-LINE-" + lineno + "--------");
        while(line.hasNext()) 
            System.out.println(line.next());
        line.close();
```

To be printed

```
Abey
F
5
5
1996
0
0
0
0
--------READING-LINE-2--------
John
M
5
5
1997
10
10
10
10
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IZlM.png "expected"

Comment: I am trying to get rid of hyphens and print everything in line.

Comment: Anyway for now I suspect you may be looking for `line.useDelimiter("[\t \r-]");` or for safer usage if you would decide to add more characters after it `line.useDelimiter("[\t \r\\-]");`. Let me know if that gave results you wanted and if you need farther explanation.

Comment: "print everything in line" usually indicates printing in one line which is *horizontal*, but your example shows *vertical* "expected" result which is little confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it in a vertical. Thank you for your help. The code you provided gave me the results I wanted. Further explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to split on each tab, space, line separator (probably not only `\r` but also `\n` or `\r\n` sequence) AND hyphen `-`.

First problem with your approach is that `line.useDelimiter("-");` *replaced* previously chosen delimiter `line.useDelimiter("[\t \r]");`.

What you need is to provide *one* delimiters which combines both settings. Tricky part is that hyphen `-` inside `[..]` would be metacharacter which wouldn't represent `-` but indicate *range*. It is because Scanner expects regex (regular expression) to form delimiter, but in regex [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (the `[...]` thing) allows user to provide *range* of characters like `a-z` (instead of writing `[abcde...z]`) so hyphen `-` is treated there as special character.

To make it *literal* we need to escape `-` it inside `[..]`. To do so we can:

- place `\` before it (which in String literals needs to be written as `"\\"`),
- or place it at position which would prevent it from being considered by regex engine as range indicator like

  - at start of character class `[-...]`
  - or at end of it `[...-]`.

But safer option is to escape it explicitly with `"\\-"` because it would allow you to safely modify that regex without any surprises (for instance if you have regex like `[a-ek-]`, if you want to add `z` you would probably write `[a-ek-z]` but that wouldn't represent `a-e` OR `k` OR `-` OR `z` but `a-z` OR `k-z`. As you see if you had `[a-ek-\]` adding single letter `z` as delimiter would result in regex `[a-ek\-z]` which was what we ware after).

So you can use `line.useDelimiter("[\t \r\\-]");`

OR to also handle other line separators like `\n` or `\r\n` *sequence* use `\R` (which can't be used inside character class because it doesn't represent only single character but also `\r\n` sequence). So to use it we would need to use `|` (OR operator) like

`line.useDelimiter("[\t \\-]|\\R");`